# Lost permission for anyone to access my websites

Tags: iis

Yesterday I mysteriously lost the permission to remote desktop to my Windows 2008 server as Administrator. At the same time when trying to access my website I got a window up prompting me for a user name and password to view the website.

Anyway, my hosting provider believe I've been hacked. Ok now, I have remote access, but what setting must I change in IIS to allow anyone to view the websites hosted on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Properties for the web site, you will select Directory Security. Click the Edit button under Authentication and Access Control.  Make sure Anonymous is checked.